# Diagonal length of viewport using plain CSS

Tags: css, css-calc

My goal is to create a absolutely-positioned circle with radius equal to the viewport's (`sv*`) diagonal length.

[image]

I tried calculating the diagonal length of the viewport based on the width and height using the Pythagorean Theorem like so:

```css
.circle {
    --radius: sqrt(calc(calc(100svw * 100svw) + calc(100svh * 100svh)));
    ...
}
```

but this failed because in `calc` multiplication, at least one of the arguments has to be a number.

I know with JavaScript it's possible to calculate the diagonal length of the viewport, but is it possible with plain CSS?

Comment: This is not a valid syntax. and `sqrt` has almost not support. Try to explain what's your goal, there might be a workaround. (if you are trying to make perfect circle, `border-radius: 9999px;` will do.

Comment: You may not use `sqrt()` either as it doesn't have good [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=sqrt()). But you can use CSS preprocessor if you want.

Comment: @ATP Heck, `999px` is enough for any size circle smaller than a big screen TV.

Comment: "*My goal is to create a absolutely-positioned circle with radius equal to the viewport's (sv*) diagonal length.*" So... this sounds like a complicated way of saying you want a circle that is as tall and as wide as the viewport?

Comment: @TylerH You can't ever know, that's the value in Tailwind for `rounded` class, I didn't overthink it.

Comment: @ATP My bad, the goal is to make a circle that can stretch from size 0 to fill the screen and also shrink to disappear. Hopefully [this example](https://tctct.pages.dev/) makes more sense (top-right button). The issue with JS is that zooming out breaks it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan for non-rectangle

Comment: @ATP a "circle" ***is*** a square with border-radius: 50%. No need to invent magic radius numbers like 999px or 9999px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple alternative would be to add the viewport width and height together, and use that as your radius.

```js
const toggle = () => {
  document.querySelector('.d1').classList.toggle('big')
  setTimeout(toggle, 4000)
}
setTimeout(toggle, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.d1 {
  width: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.big {
  width: calc(100vh + 100vw);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
```

Comment: Adding them together seems too big.  A 1024x768 display would make a 1792x1792 element.  Use `width: max(100vh, 100vw)` instead to just use whichever value is larger. It will now only ever exceed the size in one dimension, not both.

Comment: @ChrisBarr might `width: 100vmax` also work as well as that?

Comment: Yep I suppose that is right @CornOnTheCob, I forgot about `vmax` units since I haven't needed to use them much

Comment: I thought of that, but it's not big enough. A circle with a **diameter** of max(100vw, 100vh) won't quite cover the corners.

Comment: `calc(1.42 * 100vmax)` will cover the corners. 100% guarantee. sqrt(2) is 1.4142135...

Comment: `min(calc(100vh + 100vw), calc(1.42 * 100vmax))` seems better

Comment: @Kosh `~1.42` but for a perfect square. You forgot that the viewport is not a perfect square.

Comment: @jwseph `calc(100vh + 100vw)` inside a `min(` ...  alongside with `calc(1.42 * 100vmax)`??

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if `a` is the longer leg of a right triangle, `b` is the shorter leg, and `c` is the hypotenuse, we can say that `c = a*sec(B) <= a*sqrt2` because `B <= 45deg` means `sec(B) <= sqrt2`, so it works

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, basically, if we're maximizing the diagonal, we're coming to the perfect square with the side of 100vmax even though the viewport is not perfect square.

Comment: @Kosh well... https://jsfiddle.net/y9mxazd3/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, you're right. if we move the circle from the center of the viewport, we need to add that shift in our formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider `clip-path`, you don't need complex math

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: red;
  clip-path: circle(50px); /* starting value */
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
html:hover .box {
  clip-path: circle(71%); /* 71% ~ 100%/sqrt(2) */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can easily adjust the position of the clip-path:

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: red;
  clip-path: circle(50px at top right); /* starting value */
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
html:hover .box {
  clip-path: circle(71%); /* 71% ~ 100%/sqrt(2) */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```